# How to calculate the mode of a probability distribution

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I was wondering if there is any command to get the mode of the probability distributions. Calculating manually, the mode is (alpha-1)/(alpha+beta-2)

While the mean, median or variance of the beta dist can be found. For example, the mean can be found using this following command:

```
Mean[BetaDistribution[α, β]]
```

As suggested by @kguler , this command `ArgMax[PDF[BetaDistribution[2, 3], x], x]` works perfectly fine. However, when I changed the value of the parameters to something like thousands, the running process took a very long time.

Is there any other command that will produce the results much faster?

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! It might be easier for everyone if you pick a more distinctive user name. As to your question, [`Commonest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Commonest.html) gives the mode of a list, so you could do this on a sample, but I assume what you really want is to get the maximum of the `PDF` by taking the derivative and solving for zero?

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion! I will change my username soon :) I have tried use commonest but here is what I got: Commonest::arg1: The first argument is expected to be a list.

Comment: For numeric parameters, you can use `mode=ArgMax[PDF[your distribution, x],x]`: for example,`ArgMax[PDF[BetaDistribution[2, 3], x], x]` gives `1/3`.

Comment: my only problem with this command is that it takes ages in my Mathematica to run it with very large numeric parameters value. :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Experience working with distributions suggests analyzing the *logarithm* of the density function, rather than the density itself.  Because the log is a monotonic increasing transformation, the mode of the log density occurs at the same value as the mode of the density.  (This approach has general application, not just for beta distributions.)

**Let's develop this solution in steps,** asking *Mathematica* to simplify as much as possible at each stage.  First, the distribution itself:

```
f[x_, {a_, b_}] := PDF[BetaDistribution[a, b]][x]
```

(Bear in mind that this is defined only for positive values of $a$ and $b$.)

Now, its logarithm.  Take care to avoid places where the distribution will be zero or undefined:

```
g[x_, {a_, b_}] := Evaluate[Simplify[Log[f[x, {a, b}]], Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]]
```

We plan to inspect the zeros of its derivative for the mode:

```
h[x_, {a_, b_}] := Evaluate[Simplify[D[g[x, {a, b}], {x}]]]
```

The critical points will include all zeros of the derivative:

```
criticalPoints = Solve[h[x, {a, b}] == 0, {x}]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{-1+a}{-2+a+b}\right\}\right\}$

---

If we're working blindly with an unfamiliar distribution, **we had better check the endpoints to make sure that one of them isn't actually a mode, too.**  This can be problematic, because *Mathematica* often will have trouble finding the limiting values for symbolic parameters $a$ and $b$.  One alternative is to explore the situation graphically and manipulate $a$ and $b$ over reasonable ranges:

```
Manipulate[
 TableForm[{"Value at 0: " <> ToString[Limit[f[x, {a, b}], x -> 0, Direction -> -1]], 
   "Value at 1: " <> ToString[Limit[f[x, {a, b}], x -> 1, Direction -> 1]], 
   Plot[f[x, {a, b}], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 400]}], 
     {{a, 1/2}, 0, 2}, {{b, 3/2}, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Beta distribution with a mode at 0]

This will quickly show that

- When $a \lt 1$, there is a mode at $0$.
- When $b \lt 1$, there is a mode at $1$.
- Otherwise, when both $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$, the mode is at $\frac{a-1}{[a-1] + [b-1]}$, as given by the value of `criticalPoints`.

When both $a \lt 1$ and $b \lt 1$, the distribution is bimodal ("U shaped").

Comment: @whubber, thank you for such a detail and useful explanation. However, where should I input my numeric parameters into? I have tried to input the value into last equation and when I define the dist, but it doesnt work.

Comment: They are `a` and `b`.  As an example of one way to obtain the answer for, say, $a=10000$ and $b=15000$, run the steps up to obtaining `criticalPoints` and then use `criticalPoints /. {a -> 10000, b -> 15000}`. The whole point is that *Mathematica* has given you this simple formula for the mode, so once you have it you might as well use it.

Answer (score 8):

You can just calculate the derivative of the corresponding `PDF` and then set it to zero; for generic `α, β` this will not give a very nice result without additional manipulations (however the general solution is there).

```
Reduce[Simplify[D[PDF[BetaDistribution[α, β], x], x], 
   Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}] == 0, x]
```

For numeric values of the distribution parameters you get a much cleaner answer in most cases :

```
Reduce[Simplify[D[PDF[BetaDistribution[1/2, 1/3], x], x], 
 Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}] == 0 , x]
(* x == 3/7 *)
```

For numeric values however I'd suggest using the answer provided by @kguler (for `α = 1, β = 2` my method fails because the `PDF` is a linear function).

Comment: will this work if I substitute the parameters with numerical values? Cause I tried to use your suggestion with alpha=1 and beta=2 but then it gives me this message:PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.